# Quasar Cordova Google Maps Plugin

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, cordova-plugins, quasar-framework

I have been trying to use a cordova google map plugin from https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps and am yet to get it to run smoothly on my android.

I found the code

I've tried a couple other github repos for google maps but still no luck.

```
<q-page class="q-pa-xl">
    <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
    <div id="map_canvas">
      <button id="button">Click me!</button>
    </div>

</q-page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Map',
  created () {
    // Vuex get the map lat/lng
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
    var div = document.getElementById('map_canvas')

    // Create a Google Maps native view under the map_canvas div.
    //var map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div)
    var map = window.plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div)

    // If you click the button, do something...
    var button = document.getElementById('button')
    button.addEventListener('click', function () {
      // Move to the position with animation
      map.animateCamera({
        target: {lat: 37.422359, lng: -122.084344},
        zoom: 17,
        tilt: 60,
        bearing: 140,
        duration: 5000
      })

      // Add a maker
      var marker = map.addMarker({
        position: {lat: 37.422359, lng: -122.084344},
        title: 'Welecome to \n' +
                'Cordova GoogleMaps plugin for iOS and Android',
        snippet: 'This plugin is awesome!',
        animation: window.plugin.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
      })

      // Show the info window
      marker.showInfoWindow()
    })
    }, false)
  }
}
</script>
```

I've added     `<preference name="GOOGLE_MAPS_ANDROID_API_KEY" value="my api key" />` to my config.xml file in src-cordova as well. I tried to test the app on my phone but it is stuck in Apache Cordova Device is ready blinking.

Comment: What errors do you get and what does your map look like? Does the map load if you run it in browser platform? Also double check that you've added a valid API key and enabled the Maps APIs and billing for your project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you've followed the exact instructions and used the full exact code from the plugin's [latest documentation](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.6.0/hello-world/README.md). Double check that you've added a valid API key and that the JS API is enabled on your project.

I installed this plugin and followed these instructions myself, and had the same issue regarding the map not initializing and being stuck in "Cordova Device is ready" view when I ran it in Android Studio.

So I tried with the command `cordova run android` indicated in the documentation and got the following error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where: 
> Build file '\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 20
>
> What went wrong: 
> A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
> Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.1.1. Current version is 4.10.3. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in \gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

So I did just that; replaced gradle version 4.10.3 with 5.1.1.

gradle.wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Then I reran the app and the map showed up. Hope this works for you too.